# Get The Coordinates From My App to Uber (ios, swift4)

Tags: ios, swift, coordinates, uber-api

I just wondering if I can intent coordinates to Uber app like Android.

For Android I did like below:

```
requestButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent i;
        PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
        try {
            i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.ubercab");
            if (i == null)
                throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
            i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:"+ job.getCompany().getLat()+
                    ","+ job.getCompany().getLon()+
                    "?q="+ job.getCompany().getLat()+","+ job.getCompany().getLon()+
                    "("+ job.getCompany().getName()+")"));
            i.setPackage("com.ubercab");
            startActivity(i);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

            coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.cord);

            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(coordinatorLayout, "Please install Uber App", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Install", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.ubercab"));
                             startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });

            snackbar.show();
        }
```

For Swift 4 I did like this.

```
if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"uber://")!)) {
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Uber Ride", style: .default, handler: { (alert) in
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "uber://?ll=\(location.coordinate.latitude),\(location.coordinate.longitude)&navigate=no")!, options:[:], completionHandler: nil)
    }))
}
```

And yeah it does go to Uber app from my app, but it doesn't intent with coordinate too like Android. My question is, is it possible to do like Android to intent to other app with coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

The [Uber iOS app has a URL scheme](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/deep-links/introduction#standard-deep-links) that you can use to achieve what you're asking. They also provide an [Uber Rides iOS SDK](https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk) that allows you to easily generate the deep links by providing coordinates, etc.